# How to find file on android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have created this file on my device:

```
file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/mypdf.pdf
```

But I can’t figure out how to find that file manually using my android device. Any ideas?
Note: I am using an emulator, Nexus 5X.

Comment: Use Android Studio's Device File Explorer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "manually"?

You can not access this file from another application on your Android device, such as a file manager or a PDF viewer.

This is because you created it inside your applications `files` directory, which is guarded by file system permissions and is only accessible to your application.

There are two exceptions to this rule:

1. If your device is rooted, you can use [Root explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20explorer) to find the file.
2. If you created the file with ["world readable"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) permission, another application can read it if it has the exact path (including full file name).
   Note this may not work on newer versions of Android.

If you wish to access the file from you PC to examine it, you can use `adb pull` command. Since you are using an emulator, ADB should be running as root.
If it is not, use `adb root` command to switch ADB to run as root, then you will have no problem accessing any directory on the phone.

Keep in mind, this will not work on a real phone with stock ROM, as ADB can not run with root privileges on production systems.

Comment: By manually I simply mean as a normal phone user as opposed to pro-grammatically.
Thanks that info is very useful.  I am trying to open the file with my code and it is failing in google pdf viewer saying it is an invalid file.  Could that simply be a permissions issue?

Comment: Yes. Google PDF viewer can not read files in your apps directory. You need to use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and create the file on the virtual `sdcard` directory, then it will be available to all apps. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Thanks so much.  I didn't even think it might be a permissions issue.  I was stuck for ages on this.  Didn't help the message was "Invalid format"!